# Key pressing is not perfectly working in remote desktop

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop, desktop

I'm currently using RCdesktop Application on my iPad to access my desktop.

My desktop is based on Windows where everything works fine.
But repeatedly pressing the button input is recognized as a single input when I execute some programs such as games or other exe files.

What I tried to do:

1. Search for another remote desktop app such as Teamviewer, .. every application on the Apple store.-> but the TeamViewer does not work properly, same as others such as Chrome remote desktop.
2. Looking for remote input of the program -> not correctly working.
3. Looking for options for the RC desktop -> no option can be found for the input problem.

What I want to do: build and test the unreal engine project. I can move with the mouse of course, but continuously looking for a better option.

Comment: Have you tried the official [Microsoft RDP Client](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/remote-desktop-mobile/id714464092)?  You mention several other remote access clients, and claim they weren’t working properly, but you never said what wasn’t working exactly.  As currently written, this appears to be a product support question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because customer/product support questions are off-topic per the [help].

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Yeah, I'm currently using Microsoft RDP client.